# Static variable in an ES6 module (only initialised once)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following code, which happens to be a sane implementation of Redux in under 20 lines. 
I want `state`, `beforeSetStateCallbacks` and `afterSetStateCallbacks` to only be initialised once the first time the module is imported. I really want this code to be as short as possible, and to be in one file. Is there a better way to do it, which doesn't require polluting the `window` object with a global variable?

```
let state
let beforeSetStateCallbacks
let afterSetStateCallbacks

if (!window.REDUCS_INITIALISED) {
  window.REDUCS_INITIALISED = 1
  state = {}
  beforeSetStateCallbacks = []
  afterSetStateCallbacks = []
}

export const beforeSetState = (fn) => beforeSetStateCallbacks.push(fn)
export const afterSetState = (fn) => afterSetStateCallbacks.push(fn)

export const setState = async (key, value) => {
  for (const fn of beforeSetStateCallbacks) await fn(key, value)
  state[key] = value
  for (const fn of afterSetStateCallbacks) await fn(key, value)
}

export const getState = (key) => {
  return state[key]
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to assign to `window.REDUCS_INITIALISED` inside the `if` block?

Comment: Crap I did... And it still works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ES6 module's top level code will already only run once, when the module is imported for the first time. Subsequent imports of the module will simply acquire a reference to the exported items. So, you can just change the code to unconditionally create the 3 variables on the top level:

```
const state = {}
const beforeSetStateCallbacks = []
const afterSetStateCallbacks = []
```

Comment: I had huge red herrings telling me that the code was executed... and it wasn't. I have only ever used ES6 for classes... so there. I should have known better...